# Remote Mac OS X server using Windows 7 with VNC

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, vnc

I've search most of the topic around here in @SuperUser and around most of the webs they can easily access Windows uing Mac OS X but I have a question can I access my Mac using Windows?

I've activate my screen sharing on my Mac OS X and I can use another Macbook to access it no problem but once I use TightVNC or UltraVNC and any VNC base program non of them really worked for me.

So is there any alternative to VNC to give me option to access my Mac using VNC or something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean none of them really work.  Do they not connect at all, or do they connect, and perform badly?

Comment: @Zoredache it doesn't even connect for me at all, saying something about the security support not sure what was the error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a VNC compatibility password on your Mac?  By default, OS X's VNC server expects clients to authenticate with a username and password, but most VNC clients can only send a password.  To set a computer-based VNC password, go into System Preferences -> Sharing pane -> Screen Sharing (or Remote Management, if you have that enabled) -> Computer Settings, and enable "VNC viewers may control screen with password:" and enter a password.